# Handling tabs with Angular CDK FocusKeyManager

Tags: angular, angular-material, accessibility, angular-cdk

I am using the CDK FocusKeyManager to manages a list of items based on keyboard interaction. The individual items can receive native focus. This works fine and I am able to tab through the items as well as navigate via the keyboard keys.

Problem is that the FocusKeyManager gets confused if I start mixing those two ways to navigate (via tab and arrow keys). It seems that the manager is not tracking the active item correctly. If I start moving the focus via arrow keys, then continue with the tab key and then return to arrow keys, the focus will continue at the point where I left with the arrow keys and not where the current focus is.

As this is quite hard to describe, I have created a StackBlitz to play around with: https://stackblitz.com/edit/cdk-focuskeymanager-zfy8pt.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't know if it's by design, but it seems `FocusKeyManager.activeItemIndex` doesn't get updated when using the tab/shift+tab keys, but does when using the arrow keys: https://stackblitz.com/edit/cdk-focuskeymanager-cbvekw?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts Looking at the [source for FocusKeyManager](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/a11y/key-manager/list-key-manager.ts), it seems as tho it doesn't consider tab/shift+tab for navigating so I suspect the navigation is happening due to browser tabbing and not linked to the `FocusKeyManager`

Comment: hello can you resolve this? i have a same issue :(

Comment: same problem here, did you find a solution? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working for me now, I listen to the focus event on the item, and set the active item of the keymanager of the parent.

Child Component:

```
private _parent = inject(ParentComponent);
constructor() {
    fromEvent(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'focus')
        .pipe(takeUntilDestroyed())
        .subscribe(() => {
            this._parent.setActiveItem(this.id);
        });
}
```

Parent Component:

```
public setActiveItem(id: number) {
    this._keyManager?.setActiveItem(id);
}
```